# json library return non valid json for None type

Tags: python, json, nonetype

When I try to serialize a None object using json library I get the 'null' string which is not a valid JSON according to several validation tools that I found in  [json.org](http://json.org/) ([jslint](http://www.jslint.com/), [json parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)).

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(None)
'null'
```

First is it correct to try serializing an None object? If yes what should be the result ('{}'?)? If not what solutions if I want return None in my web service?

Comment: `None` is not a valid JSON Entity. So, if your content type is JSON, then your web service cannot return `None`

Comment: @thefourtheye why json doesn't raise exception for None?

Comment: `json` module tries to convert `None` to its JSON equivalent, which is `null`.

Comment: @thefourtheye can you give a link to spec that say that null is the equivalent of None?

Comment: Check the table in [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder). It is not as per JSON Spec as it is not concerned about Python's types, but `json` module implements it that way

Answer (score 0):

`null` is a perfectly valid JSON string. In a JS console:

```
> JSON.parse('null')
null
```

Comment: Can give a link to spec that say so or it is just related to JavaScript? I have edited my question and I provided link to the tool that consider null a non valid json